# Tkinter Progressbar Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This is more of a personally specific question so it won't appeal to others very much but I need help formulating my progress bar, I already have most of it down from some other stack links but it just stays empty any help?

Here is where I construct the progress bar ( It renders fine )

```
self.pb = ttk.Progressbar(self.pbLabel, orient="horizontal", length=200, mode="indeterminate")
```

Then I want to call this function when I press this button:

Button:

```
self.add_points = tk.Button(self.settingsLabel,
                            text=u"Add points",
                            command=self.gainPoint)
```

Function:

```
def gainPoint(self):
    # run once the player has completed a word
    if self.difficulty == self.difficulties["Easy"]:
        self.pointValue += 1
    if self.difficulty == self.difficulties["Medium"]:
        self.pointValue += 1.5
    if self.difficulty == self.difficulties["Hard"]:
        self.pointValue += 2
    while self.pointValue >= (self.levelValue + 5):
        self.levelValue += 1
        self.pointValue -= (self.levelValue + 5)
        if self.pointValue < 0:
            self.pointValue = 0

    self.pointsVar.set(self.pointValue)
    self.levelVar.set(self.levelValue)
    self.pb["maximum"] = self.levelValue + 5
    self.pb["value"] = self.pointValue
```

I think it has something to do when I do the `self.pb["value"]` or `self.pb["maximun"]` Please help!

The expected out come should be when I press the `self.add_points` button it should increase the progressbar by a bit based on the `self.levelValue + 5`

Comment: I have also tried switching `indeterminate` to `determinate`

Comment: problem can be because your code blocks `mainloop` which updates widgets data, redraws widgets, and do many other things. You can try to use `root.update()` inside `while` to force `mainloop` to update widgets. Or use `root.after(milliseconds, function_name)` instead of `while` so `mainloop` will execute `function_name()` and update widgets almost in parallel.

Comment: Shouldn't it pretty much instantly happen and then continue where it was like normal programs? Should I put the widget in before I call gainPoint?

Comment: it happends instantly because `mainloop` is doing this. But when you click button then `mainloop` executes your function `gainPoint` and wait untill it ends - and after your function ends `mainloop` can work again and it can redraw `progressbar` with new values. So problem is `while` loop - try `root.update()` inside this loop to let mainloop to update/redraw widgets.